# Multiple mailservers

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04, dovecot, mail-server

I am trying to find out if I am attempting the impossible.

I have

- List item
- 1 IP on 1 cloud server
- 4 x Domains that I receive mail for
- 4 x SSL certificates

I would like them all on one server.

What I currently have is all domains configured to mail.mailserver1.com

The problem with that is because the SSL mismatch then they often end up in spam.

Is it possible to have all on one server with 1 IP

example@domain1.com    >    mail.mailserver1.com > ssl1

example@domain2.com    >    mail.mailserver2.com > ssl2

example@domain3.com    >    mail.mailserver3.com > ssl3

example@domain4.com    >    mail.mailserver4.com > ssl4

Or is this impossible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt the SSL certificate is the reason for it ending up on in the spamfolder. Instead, setup an SPF record for each domain.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting maybe an overlook will try that thank you very much

Comment: yeah, its something I see daily. For many of our clients we have multiple domains, all pointing to one mailserver. The mailserver has one SSL that does not match the domains obviously but all works well because we've setup SPF records for each domain which basically says: these ip addresses are trustworthy.

Comment: Ignoring that (as above) SSL is unlikely to be the issue, you can get a multidomain cert which would fix that problem.